# How to bind a function to an animation end in RaphaëlJS?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Say I have triggered some animation, for instance

```
object.animate({transform:'R0,100,100'},300,'>')
```

How to bind a function that will fire when this animation finishes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Raphaël docs](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate) you can add a callback function as last parameter:

```
object.animate({transform:'R0,100,100'},300,'>', 
    function() { alert("Alert after the animation end!") })
```